# npm install error on console, postinstall npm ERR! code 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I used `postinstall` in my node project with react and it gives a lot of errors when installing in react.

```
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client  
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos    
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed      
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1     
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! 'npm' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete 
log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_30_16_435Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_30_10_417Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_30_05_805Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_30_01_112Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:    
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_56_359Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_51_753Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_47_154Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_42_728Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_38_177Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_33_966Z-debug-0.log       
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_29_621Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_25_136Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_20_836Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_29_16_563Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_28_54_551Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\davie\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Dev\node\videos
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm install --prefix client

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\davie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-18T03_28_52_710Z-debug-0.log
```

My `packpage.json`

```
"scripts" {
    "start:client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "start:node": "nodemon index.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \" npm run start:node\" \"npm run start:client\"",
    "postinstall": "npm install --prefix client"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on this portion here:

> 'npm' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

It seems like your Windows Command Prompt PATH is misconfigured and can't find the `npm` command.

If you're not using Windows Command Prompt to run this command, it seems like the postinstall script is using it regardless, which suggests you need to configure your development environment to use the correct shell.